# Parsing objects with several keys on the same index

Tags: javascript

I am struggeling to parse the following object, which I am getting from an input-form field:

```
const obj = { 'repeater-group[1][titel]': 'test1',
  'repeater-group[1][description]': 'test1',
  'repeater-group[3][titel]': 'test2',
  'repeater-group[3][description]': 'test2',
  'repeater-group[5][titel]': 'test3',
  'repeater-group[5][description]': 'test3' }

const desc = 'undefined'
const titel = 'undefined'
let i = 0
for (const k in obj) {
    const item = obj[k]

    if (k === `repeater-group[${i}][titel]`) {
        titel = item
    }
    if (k === `repeater-group[${i}][description]`) {
        desc = item
    }
    if (titel != 'undefined' && desc != 'undefined') {
        try {
            console.log(titel + ", " + desc)
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    i += 1
}
// Currently there is no output
```

I would like to have the following output

```
//Expected output
// test1, test1
// test2, test2
// test3, test3
```

Any suggestions what is wrong with my code?

Is there even a shorter way to do this object parsing?

I highly appreciate your replies!

Comment: `titel` and `desc` are constants, and you're trying to assign to them. You need to make them variables.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I changed the variables to `let`. Still I get no output.

Comment: That's because both of your variables are `undefined`, and so your logic never enters the conditional. If you chain an `else` to `if (titel != 'undefined' && desc != 'undefined')` you logic will enter it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match the parts of the key you want to work with via a regular expression:

```js
const obj = {
  'repeater-group[1][titel]': 'test1',
  'repeater-group[1][description]': 'test1',
  'repeater-group[3][titel]': 'test2',
  'repeater-group[3][description]': 'test2',
  'repeater-group[5][titel]': 'test3',
  'repeater-group[5][description]': 'test3'
}

const out = {}

for (const key in obj) {
  const value = obj[key]

  const match = /repeater-group\[([0-9])\]\[([a-z]+)\]/.exec(key)
  const index = match[1]
  const property = match[2]
  
  out[index] = {...out[index], [property]: value} 
}

console.log(out)

/*
{
  "1": {
    "titel": "test1",
    "description": "test1"
  },
  "3": {
    "titel": "test2",
    "description": "test2"
  },
  "5": {
    "titel": "test3",
    "description": "test3"
  }
}
*/

Object.keys(out).forEach(i => console.log(`${out[i].titel}, ${out[i].description}`))

/*
test1, test1
test2, test2
test3, test3
*/
```